# What's the best way to set up a two way TCP communication of equal clients without a server?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking, tcp

I want to create a three way communication system in which every party has equal rights, with two communication channels to his partners.
The program is decentralized and every machine runs the same code, in which there is a list of three IP addresses, with every one representing one of the machines. For each machine the partners' IP addresses are determined by looking at it's own IP address and using the other two from the list.

Now there is no predetermined order in which the machines are being turned on, is there any way to control the TCP communication other than setting it something like
'if the IP address you want to speak to is higher than your own, connect to a server, otherwise you are the server and accept sockets'?

In the end I want a `TCPread(port)` which fires every time a message from any IP comes in and a `TCPwrite(port, ip, message)` which sents a message.

My idea was a TCPhandler which stores all sockets it's got for every port I plan on using in the programm with one thread per port. Then everytime a read or write is performed it checks if there is a socket for the port and IP address in the handler, if not it sends a socket to the IP and waits for a response... I don't think i've understood that whole TCP thing entirely though.

Comment: Well understand one thing... There is always going to be `one server`... But yeah from what you want its something like dynamic..

Comment: Have you investigated http://jgroups.org/?

Comment: I know there *is always gonna be* a server, I just dont know where and how to negotiate which party does what in this case. @Mark: this seems a little over the top, the communication is intended to be very basic.

Comment: I would make them all servers, and have them all try to connect to each other. The earliest of the two connections between each pair wins.

Comment: If two peers want to connect to each other, one of them needs to act as a client and the other needs to act as a server. If either party is behind a NAT/firewall, it may take a couple of tries flip-flopping roles to establish a connection. If both parties are behind NATs/firewalls, it is very difficult to make a connection without one of them opening up their system or using hole-punching techniques. Most popular peer-to-peer systems utilize a centralized server to coordinate the establishment of peer-to-peer connections, or act as a proxy when a peer-to-peer connection is not possible

Comment: @nO_OnE_910 JGroups may seem over the top but you don't need to use everything. For server-less TCP messaging between 3 nodes it fits the bill and I don't see the point in reinventing the wheel. Hazelcast would be another (slightly simpler) option I would consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about number of connections you can do following:

- Each peer open port and listen for incoming connections
- Try to establish connections to each peer with some period of time

As result you will get two connection between each peer. Now you can use them following way:

- Outgoing connections are used for sending messages
- Incoming connections are used for receiving messages

Comment: I didn't know you could use the same port for two sockets to the same client! I'll try that later today and will report back

Comment: @nO_OnE_910 You don't use same port for two sockets. One (for outgoing connection) is dynamic, you don't need exact value...